# Turn off syntax error marks for custom keywords in CDT

Tags: java-8, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Developing with CDT can become frustrating, because nobody answers your questions and there is hardly any documentation. That being said, let me try it with a simple one:

In my eclipse plugin the user wants to edit files with a language similar to C++. To have additional keywords highlighted, I created a class that extends GPPScannerExtensionConfiguration like this:

```
public class GRASPScannerExtensionConfiguration extends GPPScannerExtensionConfiguration {

    private static GRASPScannerExtensionConfiguration instance;

    public static synchronized GRASPScannerExtensionConfiguration getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new GRASPScannerExtensionConfiguration(version(8, 0));
        return instance;
    }

    public GRASPScannerExtensionConfiguration(int version) {
        super(version);

        /*
         * add GRASP specific configuration
         */
        addKeyword("@func".toCharArray(), IToken.t_void);
        addKeyword("@tag".toCharArray(), IToken.t_void);
    }
}
```

With this class I have my keywords `@func` or `@tag` highlighted like `void` in C++. But the editor underlines those keywords and says "Syntax error".

I know I can deactivate syntax error in `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations` but that would 1.) deactivate all syntax errors and 2.) require users to manually do this setting.

How can I deactivate the syntax error marking only for my own additional keywords?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I deactivate the syntax error marking only for my own additional keywords?

The short answer is you can't.

The parser doesn't have a way of distinguishing between "a syntax error caused by your additional keyword" and "a syntax error caused by something else" without being taught such a way. It also doesn't have a way to recover the parse after encounting such a keyword, such that subsequent parts of a declaration (or expression or whatever context the keyword appears in) are parsed correctly, again without being taught such a way.

To teach the parser these things, you'd have to modify / extend it in new ways. I'm not aware of current extension points that would allow you to do this, so you'd have to fork the plugin providing the parser, or upstream new extension points to it.

Comment: Could the extension ppoint `org.eclipse.cdt.corel.ErrorParser` help here?

Comment: @Sadik `IErrorParser` is for parsing error messages from compiler output, so that the error messages can be presented in the Problems view. There is no relation to the syntax errors produced by CDT's parser.

Comment: What about extending `GNUCPPSourceParser` and `GPPParserExtensionConfiguration` ?

Comment: Extending `GNUCPPSourceParser` might work if you're able to override the relevant methods. Where do these new keywords appear grammatically? Is there some documentation for the language extension you're trying to implement?

Comment: For example `@func` precedes function definitions and can be combined with static or volatile, like `@func static void private_function() {...}` Another one is `@call` which is used to call functions (in a certain way) like `@call(private_function())`. Those are already the most important ones. All of them start with '@'. There is a user manual, but for customers only. It's not that interesting.

Comment: Ok, so `@func` is a *decl-specifier*. You can try overriding `GNUCPPSourceParser.declSpecifierSeq()` and handling it there, but you'd basically need to copy the existing implementation to continue handling existing decl-specifiers. You'd want to add a `case` to [this](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.core/parser/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/parser/cpp/GNUCPPSourceParser.java#n3234) big `switch` and basically just ignore it. You may run into trouble as the existing implementation uses private fields of GNUCPPSourceParser.

Comment: `@call` is an expression, so you could override `GNUCPPSourceParser.expression()`. You can lookahead to check for the `@call` token - if you see it, consume it, as well as a `(`, then call the base `expression()`, and finally consume a `)`. Otherwise, just call the base `expression()`. (A similar approach can work for `@func` (and avoid duplicating the existing implementation) if you know it will always be at the beginning of the decl-specifier-seq: just check for `@func`, consume it, and then call the base `declSpecifierSeq()`).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Indeed declSpecifierSeq is called for `@func`, but it goes to an existing case: `IToken.tIDENTIFIER`. It then calls qualifiedName() and returns "func" without @. I wonder why it has no effect which integer I chose in addKeyword(). I'm not sure if I can handle that, even when I copy those dozens of private methods into my parser subclass. I'll try.

Comment: I copied and pasted dozens of private methods and I have a custom implementation for declSpecifierSeq, which returns an empty Decl object in case the token is `tIDENTIFIER` and qualifiedName returns "func". Otherwise the superclass method is called with this big switch. I can debug and see that for func the empty Decl is returned, but unfortunately it doesn't change anything. "@func" is still underlined and it says Syntax error.

Comment: You're associating the new keywords with `IToken.t_void`? I think you need to define your own token types for them.

Comment: Oh, there's an additional problem: new keywords, as defined using `AbstractScannerExtensionConfiguration.addKeyword()`, are assumed to conform to the lexical grammar for identifiers (as all existing keywords including supported GNU extensions do). `@` is not part of the lexical grammar for identifiers. So, to support keywords containing the `@` character, you need lexer changes. Again, not sure how to do that via current extension points.

Comment: The Lexer class can't even be extended. It's declared final. I might end up forking CDT or coding everything from scratch without CDT. I still hope to find another way. Maybe instead of adding keywords, I could try to define annotations?

Comment: Forking is probably the way to go. CDT's parser is essentially a compiler front-end, and extending a compiler front-end to support language extensions without forking it is a pretty tall order. I'm willing to bet, for instance, that the frontend of the actual GRASP compiler isn't just a plugin running on top of an unmodified existing frontend like gcc or clang either, but is rather a fork of an existing frontend.

Comment: It's a program that generates C++ files based on bison grammar. After that the unmodified gcc is used.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful in deactivating syntax errors and I want to briefly write down how I did it:

1.) Write a class that extends `CPreprocessor` and overrides `handleProblem`. In my case my keyword is "@func", but It's tokenized as '@' and 'func'. The '@' is put into a list of problems which is handled in `handleProblem`.

```
import org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.parser.scanner.CPreprocessor;
...
public class GRASPPreprocessor extends CPreprocessor {
    public GRASPPreprocessor(FileContent fileContent, IScannerInfo info, ParserLanguage language, IParserLogService log,
        IScannerExtensionConfiguration configuration, IncludeFileContentProvider readerFactory) {
        super(fileContent, info, language, log, configuration, 
    }

    @Override
    public void handleProblem(int id, char[] arg, int offset, int endOffset) {
        if (new String(arg).equals("@")) {
            this.problem = new ProblemStorage(id, arg, offset, endOffset);
        } else {
            super.handleProblem(id, arg, offset, endOffset);
        }
    }
}
```

I created a short Storage class to store the arguments. But only call the superclass's `handleProblem` method, if the "@" is not followed by "func". This is done in `nextToken`:

```
@Override
public IToken nextToken() throws EndOfFileException {

    IToken token = super.nextToken();
    if(problem != null && token.getType() == IToken.tIDENTIFIER) {
        if (new String(token.getCharImage()).equals("func")) {
            problem = null;
            return super.nextToken();
        } else {
            super.handleProblem(problem.id, problem.arg, problem.offset, problem.endOffset);
            return token;
        }
    }
    return token;
}
```

This basically ignores "@func". A stray '@' would still marked as a problem.

2.) Define your own language class, extending GPPLanguage and override `createScanner`:

```
protected IScanner createScanner(FileContent content, IScannerInfo scanInfo, IncludeFileContentProvider fcp,
        IParserLogService log) {
    return new GRASPPreprocessor(content, scanInfo, getParserLanguage(), log,
            getScannerExtensionConfiguration(scanInfo), fcp);
}
```

3.)
Add an extension to the plugin.xml with the extension point `org.eclipse.cdt.core.language` and also tell the plugin which content type has to be used for this language:

```
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">
  <content-type
        file-extensions="grasp"
        id="de.blub.contenttype.grasp"
        name="GRASP"
        priority="high">
  </content-type>
</extension>
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.language">
  <language
        class="de.blub.language.GRASPLanguage"
        id="de.blub.language.grasp"
        name="Great Alternative Stupid Language">
     <contentType
           id="de.blub.contenttype.grasp">
     </contentType>
  </language>
```

4.) I don't know what's wrong with the content type binding, but it's not working. I asked the community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55575534/2013672) about it. However, you can define add your own association via **Window->Preferences->General->Content Types**.